# React Navigation 6 : Remove screen which prevented by `beforeRemove` listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation-v6

I am new with React Navigation 6.

I have a screen with `beforeRemove` listener with a dialog to ask user to exit on confirmation.

My problem is the removing screen which prevented by `beforeRemove` listener.
I used `e.data.action` to exit and its works on time but sometimes i want to exit screen directly wihtout confirmation. `e.data.action` will provided when `beforeRemove` triggered.

*I googled a lot subjects but got nothing, even on [official React Navigation 6.x documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back)*

**Here is my code:**

```js
useFocusEffect(() => {
    const callback = e => {
        setActionForLater(e.data.action) // <- i used a helper variable, i dont know it helps or not, because it works after `beforeRemove` listener triggered
        e.preventDefault();
        const exitDialog = Dialog.show({
          title: 'Exit',
          subtitle: 'Do you want to exit without save?',
          buttons: [
            {
              title: 'Exit',
              textStyle: { color: '#f44' },
              onPress: () => {
                props.navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
              },
            },
            {
              title: 'Cancel',
              onPress: () => {
                Dialog.hide(exitDialog);
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    };
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', callback);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  });
```

Comment: You can simply check `if (e.data) setActionForLater(e.data.action)`

Comment: ✍️ I already used it but `e.preventDefault()` still prevent from exiting and dialog will popup everytime i use `pop`, `goBack`, `replace` ... any other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may choose `BackHandler`, rather than using `beforeRemove`, because beforeRemove will get called no matter what when leaving the screen, but BackHandler will exactly handle only the back button, see how..

```
import {BackHandler} from "react-native"
    
useEffect(() => {
    const callback = () => {
      Dialog.show({
          title: 'Exit',
          subtitle: 'Do you want to exit without save?',
          buttons: [
            {
              title: 'Exit',
              textStyle: { color: '#f44' },
              onPress: () => {
                props.navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
              },
            },
            {
              title: 'Cancel',
              onPress: () => {
                Dialog.hide(exitDialog);
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      callback
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
}, []);
```

Cheers.

Comment: thank you @iphonic , I did it and this solution worked fine. also i used this logic for `Back Button` on screen's Toolbar(Header).

Comment: this works only in android what for IOS?

Comment: @ShafqatBari There is no Hardware backbutton in iOS

Comment: @iphonic I know this. But this is only for android. I was asking about swipe in IOS. Swipe left takes user to back screen. Thats why I asked what for IOS